# Am I only missing nudity and violence?

Tags: game-of-thrones, censorship

I watch Game of Thrones on HBO in Singapore. The nudity I have heard so much about has been completely cut and I assume some of the more graphic violence has also been cut. The editing seems to be a lot better than most shows and is not that obvious.

Am I likely to be missing any major plot developments or is it all just pillow talk?

Comment: what happened to brandon stark in the first episode of season1? :)

Comment: heh I didn't know his name, but yeah he heard something then he got shoved.

Comment: If they cut out the things that brandon saw (nudity scene with a certain couple), you might have missed something important.

Comment: In that particular scene you didn't see exactly what he saw, but you could hear it and saw them covering up afterwards, so it was obvious what happened.

Comment: A majority is definitely character development which I think is integral to the plot itself because this series is so character driven.

Comment: Why not just download the uncensored series off the internets?

Comment: Huh.. didn't know HBO was censored in other parts of the world.  There are plenty of free sites to watch the episodes online.  I'd recommend them here only because you truly are missing out by not seeing everything the show offers.   Not sure if I can post a link to the site I watch the episodes on, but if not, I'll try to help further.

Comment: Unfortunately, the show uses a lot of [sexposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexposition); in fact, it is the reason the term was coined. So a lot of plot points tend to get mixed-in with "gratuitous sex-scenes". The best course of action is to probably after viewing, if something doesn't make sense after an alleged "deletion", then it's probably worth asking about it here or over at [sfi-fi!](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Personally I don't think the show would be worth watching without the sex and violence, but that might just be me.  To actually answer your question though I think many of the sex scenes actually establish character and subtleties of plot, and the same might also be said of the violence.

According to [Here be Geeks](http://www.herebegeeks.com/tv/a-game-of-censors-game-of-thrones-and-spartacus-vs-singapore-cable/) about 2-3 minutes have been cut from each hour in Singapore, and they express concerns that many of these scenes
will be integral to the plot:

> Some gore or sex could probably be safely edited out of the shows, but I fear that certain scenes will be rendered useless due to censorship. Lots of ... Game of Thrones eps have violence and gore that and *(sic)* in some way or another is integral to the plot, and while off the top of my head I think most of the boobs from Game of Thrones can be edited out, there’s that one key scene in a whorehouse that I think really speaks volumes about quite a major character and his worldview.

Comment: That doesn't sound too bad. It would of been nice if they had elaborated on the whorehouse scene so I could know what they are talking about. The only scene in a whorehouse from season 1 that I can remember involves Theon Greyjoy.

Comment: @row1, I'm sure the scene they are talking about involves a lengthy discussion between Petyr Baelish and a pair of his whores while they are at work.  The discussion establishes a bit of his history and his motives.

Comment: @John Wait, *Lord Baelish* talked about something in this scene? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not only does it really put the HBO stamp on the show and give it authenticity, but as well as this they seem to cram a lot of exposition into the sex scene's. In the first series especially. I fact who is sleeping with who can often be a pivotal plot point. Those of you who watch the uncut show know what I'm talking about. There is a sex scene between Viserys and Dorreah when we not only learn about the exctinction of the dragons, but also about Viserys child hood. There is a scene when two whores practice on each other while Lord Baelish reminisces about his childhood love. I don't know how strict the violence cuttings are but there aren't that many important points in these scenes, aside from demonstrating a characters badassery. There are however a few moments when you might suddenly go "where the heck did he go?" But aside from that one could probably live without the violence. If out in your situation I would watch each episode and then Google the events of the episode to see if there is anything important that you missed.